# how to remove spurious non ascii characters, but keep spaces and newlines?

Tags: php, strip, non-ascii-characters

I have some text files that contain some non ASCII characters, I want to remove them, however keep the formatting characters.

I tried

```
$description = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $description);
```

However that appeared to strip newlines and other formatting out and also had problems with some Hebrew which then converted this

> משפטים נוספים מהמומחה. נסו ותהנו! חג
>   חנוכה שמח
>   **************************************** חדש - האפליקציה היחידה שאומרת לך מה
>   מצב הסוללה שלך ** NEW to version 1.1 -
>   the expert talks!!! *

to this

> 1.4 :", ..."" ..."" 50 ..." . , . ! **************************************** - ** NEW to version 1.1 - the expert talks!!! *

Answer (score 3):

That's not replacing non-ASCII characters...  Ascii characters are inside of the range 0-127.  So basically what you're trying to do is write a rexeg to convert one character set to another (not just replace out some of the characters, which is a lot harder)...

As for what you want to do, I think you want the [`iconv` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php)...  You'll need to know the input encoding, but once you do you can then tell it to ignore non-representable characters:

```
$text = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//IGNORE', $text);
```

You could also use `ISO-8859-1`, or any other target character set you want.

Comment: No, he's not trying to convert character sets. He's trying to remove characters outside the ASCII range from a UTF-8 string. Of course, your solution works because ASCII is a subset of UTF-8. With ISO-8859-1, he'd get non-ASCII characters and he could no longer use the string with functions that expect UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing won't work because you're treating a UTF-8 string as if it were a single-byte encoding. You are actually removing **portions of characters**. If you must add the `u` flag to the regex expression to activate UTF-8 mode.

Since you want to leave only the control characters and the other ASCII range characters, you have to replace all the others with ''. So:

```
$description = preg_replace('/[^\x{0000}-\x{007F}]/u', '', $description);
```

which gives for your input:

```
. ! ********************* - * NEW to version 1.1 - the expert talks!!! *
```

Comment: thanks, but when I just tried that it gave me this as the output 1.4 : ", ..." " ..." " 50 ..." . , . ! **************************************** - ** NEW to version 1.1